# What to do with FileNotFoundError: Could not find module on labelme2yolo.py

Tags: python, yolov8

Whenever I try running the `labelme2yolo.py` on my windows 10 cmd, I get this:

```
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\Users\Owner\sklearn-venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\.libs\msvcp140.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
```

After checking file explorer, it's clearly in there, so I have no idea what's going wrong at this point.  What dependencies do I need to check or download for this msvcp140.dll?

I tried renaming all my files to fit the exact way the cmd prompt displayed it, but nothing worked.  I also found a previous comment on shapely but I don't believe that applies to this situation, does it? I don't know what to do at this point.

Looking at other posts, I also tried installing the Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013 but it still doesn't work, even after I set it up.